# VSCode With Live Server and Remote Tunnels opening in browser on main machine rather than laptop

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-liveserver

Using VSCode with the extension Live Server(Ritwick Dey). Connected to my desktop through Remote Tunnel. When using the extension to preview an HTML file hosted by my desktop in my browser, it opens on the desktop, rather than the laptop.

Any way around this?

I've googled everything I can think of. Doesn't seem to be any data. Checked settings for Live Server inside VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the live server by adding the ip address of the host machine.

I was facing this issue when I was tunneling into windows laptop through iPad. I added ip address of the windows laptop(host machine) followed by port on which live server serves the app (default is 5500) and I was able to access in safari OS.

For example: accessing app served by live server on safari in iPad, I enter 192.168.xx.xx:5500/test.html in the address bar